# Insert row without overwritting data

Tags: java, android, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I end up here a lot from google and since I started trying to make an android app for myself I'm stumped since the v4 API isn't very helpful. I've search on here but I haven't seen an answer that answer my question.

I have a budget spreadsheet. My app is going to grab the data from the sheet and filter it to my current payweek. So I can look at all my current transactions and future ones so I can know how much I have extra to spend. Then I want to just be able to insert a new traction from the app, say if I get gas I want to be able to add that in a couple clicks rather than try to spend a few minutes editing the sheets in the sheet app. Later I plan to customize the formula for the cell I'm putting it in as well as copy it to the cells north and south of it so the math works out.

I used [the Android Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/quickstart/android) to be able to read data easy enough. I've since tweaked that to filter the sheets data to filter my data. I've even gone as far to get it be able to write data to the sheet. The problem is that I can't find any example in java/android in the same style as the quick start to know how to insert a row in the middle of the sheet instead of overwrite the cells. I'm assuming I have to use the INSERTDATAOPTION=INSERT_ROWS somewhere but I can't find anywhere to add it. The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append) suggest I use spreadsheets.values.append but .append never shows up as an option. I only get BatchGet, BatchUpdate, Get, Update.

I'm a beginner and I'm sure my code is clumsy that I've pieced together after hours of googling but I'm sure I'm just missing something easy. Any help would be appreciated.

```html
private List<String> PostDataForApi() throws IOException {
            String spreadsheetID = getResources().getString(R.string.my_google_spreadsheet_id);
            Integer sheetID = getResources().getInteger(R.integer.my_google_sheet_id);
            
            List<RowData> rowData = new ArrayList<RowData>();
            List<CellData> cellData = new ArrayList<CellData>();

            String value = "test";
            String formula = "=IF(COUNTBLANK(C510) = 2,\"\",Sum(B511+(SUM(C510))))";
            String value2 = "999";

            CellData cell = new CellData();
            cell.setUserEnteredValue(new ExtendedValue().setStringValue(value));
            CellData cell2 = new CellData();
            cell2.setUserEnteredValue(new ExtendedValue().setFormulaValue(formula));
            CellData cell3 = new CellData();
            cell3.setUserEnteredValue(new ExtendedValue().setStringValue(value2));

            cellData.add(cell);
            cellData.add(cell2);
            cellData.add(cell3);
            rowData.add(new RowData().setValues(cellData));

            BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest batchRequests = new BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest();
            BatchUpdateSpreadsheetResponse response;
            List<Request> requests = new ArrayList<Request>();
            AppendCellsRequest appendCellReq = new AppendCellsRequest();

            appendCellReq.setSheetId(sheetID);
            appendCellReq.setRows( rowData );
            appendCellReq.setFields("userEnteredValue");

            requests = new ArrayList<Request>();
            requests.add( new Request().setAppendCells(appendCellReq));
            batchRequests = new BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest();
            batchRequests.setRequests( requests );


            response =  this.mService.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetID, batchRequests).execute();
            System.out.println(response.toPrettyString());

            return null;
        }
```

Comment: Post your answer as an answer. Don't post an answer that says to refer to an edit in your original question.

Comment: I have edited both. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out after some mind numbing throw things against the wall and see what sticks. I had to do it in two steps. The first step will insert a row into your sheet at row 32 so you'll get a blank row 33. Then the second area will insert values into that blank row. I hope this helps someone in the future.

```html
String spreadsheetID = getResources().getString(R.string.my_google_spreadsheet_id);
            Integer sheetID = getResources().getInteger(R.integer.my_google_sheet_id);

            BatchUpdateSpreadsheetResponse response;
            BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest batchRequests = new BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest();
            List<Request> requests = new ArrayList<Request>();

            InsertDimensionRequest insertDimensionRequest = new InsertDimensionRequest();
            DimensionRange dimRange = new DimensionRange();
            dimRange.setStartIndex(32);
            dimRange.setEndIndex(33);
            dimRange.setSheetId(sheetID);
            dimRange.setDimension("ROWS");

            insertDimensionRequest.setRange(dimRange);
            insertDimensionRequest.setInheritFromBefore(false);
            requests.add( new Request().setInsertDimension(insertDimensionRequest));
            batchRequests = new BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest();
            batchRequests.setRequests( requests );
            response =  this.mService.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetID, batchRequests).execute();
            System.out.println(response.toPrettyString());

            List<List<Object>> argData = getData(entryTitle, entryValue);
            ValueRange vRange = new ValueRange();
            vRange.setRange("2016!A33");
            vRange.setValues(argData);
            List<ValueRange> vList = new ArrayList<>();
            vList.add(vRange);
            BatchUpdateValuesRequest batchRequest = new BatchUpdateValuesRequest();
            batchRequest.setValueInputOption("USER-ENTERED");
            batchRequest.setData(vList);
            this.mService.spreadsheets().values().batchUpdate(spreadsheetID, batchRequest).execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been having sooo much unnecessary hustle with the v4 google sheets api, that it was ridiculous. Therefore, I reverted to the gdata (v3) api, much better easier to follow and much better documented also.

Here is the link to setting it up and a few examples https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/

The only thing missing was the authorization process in those notes, which was a hustle, but after some digging I was able to get a authorization code base, as shown below.

```
public class YourClass {
    // Application name
    private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "Your-Application-Name";

// account info and p12
private static final String ACCOUNT_P12_ID = "Get-the-details-developer-console-google";
private static final File P12FILE = new File("D:/path/Drive API Test-bf290e0ee314.p12");

// scopes
private static final List<String> SCOPES = Arrays.asList(
        "https://docs.google.com/feeds",
        "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds");

// Spreadsheet API URL
private static final String SPREADSHEET_URL = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/private/full";

private static final URL SPREADSHEET_FEED_URL;

static {
    try {
        SPREADSHEET_FEED_URL = new URL(SPREADSHEET_URL);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
// Authorize
private static Credential authorize() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("authorize in");

    HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
    JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();

    GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
            .setTransport(httpTransport)
            .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
            .setServiceAccountId(ACCOUNT_P12_ID)
            .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(P12FILE)
            .setServiceAccountScopes(SCOPES)
            .build();

    boolean ret = credential.refreshToken();
    // debug dump
    System.out.println("refreshToken:" + ret);

    // debug dump
    if (credential != null) {
        System.out.println("AccessToken:" + credential.getAccessToken());
    }

    System.out.println("authorize out");

    return credential;
}

//    Get service
private static SpreadsheetService getService() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("service in");

    SpreadsheetService service = new SpreadsheetService(APPLICATION_NAME);
    service.setProtocolVersion(SpreadsheetService.Versions.V3);

    Credential credential = authorize();
    service.setOAuth2Credentials(credential);

    // debug dump
    System.out.println("Schema: " + service.getSchema().toString());
    System.out.println("Protocol: " + service.getProtocolVersion().getVersionString());
    System.out.println("ServiceVersion: " + service.getServiceVersion());

    System.out.println("service out");

    return service;
}
```

From that onward, I was able to perform a number of inserts and appends to the sheets, without any major hustle.